# How do I fix a ReflectionException error (class doesn't exist)?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm new to drupal 8. I would like to extend the user login form by deleting the username field and adding the email field. So I created a custom module, I implemented an Event Subscriber and declared it as a service :

```
services:
    mdmuser.route_subscriber:
        class: Drupal\mdm_user\Routing\RouteSubscriber
        tags: 
             - {name: event_subscriber }
```

And here's my class RouteSubscriber

```
 <?php

 /**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mdm_user\Routing\RouteSubscriber.
 */

 namespace Drupal\mdm_user\Routing;

 use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

 /**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
 class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

 protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

     if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\mdm_user\Form\UserLoginForm');
      $collection->add('user.login', $route);
    }
  }
}
```

I have this error when I want to install my new module :

```
ReflectionException: Class Drupal\mdm_user\Routing\RouteSubscriber does not exist in ReflectionClass->__construct() (line 31 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterEventSubscribersPass.php).
```

Any idea is appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: What's the path to the file? It should be: /modules/mdm_user/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

Comment: Yes, it looks good : modules/custom/mdm_user/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

Comment: Have you done a cache rebuild since adding the code?

Comment: I cleared cache again, the module is installed. But it seems my EventSubscriber is not caught. Thank you for your help !

Comment: There already exists a module that introduces changing the username to an email field in the login flow. so I don't recommend reinventing the wheel here. The module is called [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration).

Comment: You need to check your route define in routing.yml file .. or check that your controller file is place inside src/Controller folder. Cheer !!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It has to be the file structure.  Check again that it's at /modules/custom/mdm_user/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

Also, in your class, you don't need to add the route again, it's passed by reference.

You can remove

```
$collection->add('user.login', $route);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting above error message then I suggests following things to check for,

1. Check if there are any spelling mistakes in the routing file, that
   is may be the name  you have written is something and the file name
   is something else.
2. Check the class name defined in the controller file matches the file name
3. Folder structure is something like '\Drupal\module_name\src\Controller\exampleConfig.php' but the routing file will have something like this "\Drupal\module_name\Controller\exampleConfig" don't worry about the "src" folder
4. Check your namespace if it exists or not and if properly written or not
5. Check for unnecessary extra lines in *.routing.yml of your module.
6. Add 'Controller' to end of file with your Controller Class and to end of Class Name of Controller.

I have the approach of issue with below:

Try command in bash near web/ dir of drupal  'drupal gcon', [see also](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/generate-controller.html)

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. It ended up being stupid mistake in my namespace in my RouteSubscriper.php file. I had:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber;
```

When it should have been:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;
```